# Mongodb $slice multiple values in same array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, projection

We have some time series data that we're trying to generate reports on and we're trying to optimize as much as possible. We collect 30 sensors every minute every hour. I am building a graph that will show only 2-3 sensor values for every minute. I cannot seem to get $slice to work the way I want it to so that I only receive 2 sensor values instead of 30 for every minute.

Our structure is as follows:

```
"hours" : [ 
    {
        "hour" : 0,
        "minutes" : [ 
            {
                "minute" : 0,
                "values" : [ 
                    2,
                    4,
                    7,
                    2,
                    ...
                ]
             },
             ...
    },
    ...
]
```

I can successfully slice one sensor using:

> {"hours.minutes": {$slice: [0,1]},"hours.minutes.values": {$slice: [22, 1]}

And I've tried different variations without success such as:

> {"hours.minutes": {$slice: [0,1]}, "hours.minutes.values": {$slice: [22, 1]},"hours.minutes.values": {$slice: [10, 1]}}

Is there any way to grab multiple values from the same array ("hours.minutes.values") using $slice without just grabbing a range?

Comment: According to the [$slice](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) help you can only use a range with it. Have you looked at using the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) to see if it could help you get multiple values out of the array?

Comment: Alternatively, if the aggregation isn't good enough for you, you should consider redesigning the schema to separate readings from different sensors. Have a look at the classic [time series blog post](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb).

Comment: I hadn't looked into it. I've tried to get it to work but it seems like my use case is pretty complex. Do you have an example of how I'd get it to work using aggregation?